# Conditional Coloring based on relative cell value

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2013

I know how to do [Conditional Coloring](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45670/how-to-highlight-a-row-in-excel-using-conditional-formatting/).

I also know how to use the [LookUp() command](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324986).

What I would like to know is how to color a cell when two lookup calls generate different results (see example below). As a side note, I find it absolutely astounding how if you google `conditional coloring based on another cell`, it foolishly assumes that no one would want to compare one cell to its neighbour, but instead uses a fixed cell.

**Worksheet 1: Proposed IP Schema**

```
MAC Address       IP Address
AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA 192.168.1.1
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB 192.168.1.2
```

**Worksheet 2: Data from router/switch**

```
MAC Address       IP Address
AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA 192.168.1.1
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB 192.168.1.66
```

**Worksheet 3: Master Document**

```
MAC Address       IP Address
AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA 192.168.1.1
BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB There is an IP address mismatch
```

I know how to cheat and color the cell red by issuing a unique string (in this case `There is an IP address mismatch`) then conditionally color that cell red when it encounters the string `There is an IP address mismatch`, but is there a cleaner way to do this. I would like to keep the proposed IP address, but color the background red to indicate that there is an error.

Comment: What's the formula you have that returns "!!ERROR!!"?  I'm thinking you could use a pared down version of that to determine if the two cells are the same...

Comment: @user3578951 Sorry, that is not a return value, it is a unique string. I will edit the question

Comment: I think sharing some images, formulas and what you have done so far would make it easier to answer... what do you think? ;)

Comment: @MrSimpleMind Ask and you shall receive. Have to run to a meeting. Will do this ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- get proposed address in master sheet second column
- use this in conditional formatting criteria: `=NOT(B2=VLOOKUP(A2,actual!A:B,2,FALSE))`

[image]